# Is it possible to generate multi audience claim JWT token using Azure Identity?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm reading about JWT token and understands that a single token can have multiple audiences claims so that the same token can be used with multiple resource servers. But I'm not able to find out a way to generate such token in `Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries (ADAL)`.

If you look at the `AcquireTokenAsync` function which is part of `AuthenticationContext` class, all its implementations just takes a single `resource` parameter. But I'm not able to find any written doc which says `ADAL` doesn't supports multi audience token.

Does anyone know whether its possible in `ADAL` or not?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not allowed. Azure AD issues a token for a certain resource (which is mapped to an Azure AD app). When we call AcquireTokenAsync, we need to provide a single resourceID. The result is the token can only be used for resource matching the supplied identifier.